# Setting private data members with same name as set functions parameters

Tags: c++

How would I go about setting these private members correctly:

```
private:
int x1,y1,x2,y2;
```

when the set function is set up like this:

```
void setPos(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
```

I cannot simply set x1 to x1, and I am unfortunately stuck with this implementation of the parameters and variable names.

Here is the complete header file:

```
#ifndef SHIP_H
#define SHIP_H
class Ship
{
  public:
    virtual ~Ship(void) {}
    virtual const char *name(void) const = 0;
    virtual int size(void) const = 0;
    int getX(int i) const;
    int getY(int i) const;
    void print(void) const;
    bool includes(int x, int y);
    int level(void) const;
    void decreaseLevel(void);
    static Ship *makeShip(char ch, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
  protected:
    void setPos(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    int lev;
  private:
    bool checkConfig(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    int x1,y1,x2,y2;
};

class AircraftCarrier : public Ship
{
  public:
    AircraftCarrier(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    virtual const char *name(void) const;
    virtual int size(void) const;
};

class BattleShip: public Ship
{
  public:
    BattleShip(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    virtual const char *name(void) const;
    virtual int size(void) const;
};

class Cruiser: public Ship
{
  public:
    Cruiser(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    virtual const char *name(void) const;
    virtual int size(void) const;
};

class Destroyer: public Ship
{
  public:
    Destroyer(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    virtual const char *name(void) const;
    virtual int size(void) const;
};
#endif
```

Comment: Could you list all your restrictions? Is `setPos` a member?

Comment: I added the header file to clear things up.

Comment: Why not just give them different names?

Comment: In what way are you "stuck" with the names? Do you mean you are forbidden to change parameter names in the declaration of `setPos` in Ship.h, even though this would have no impact on any calls to `setPos`? Apparently at least you must be allowed to edit some part of the _implementation_ of `setPos` in another file--are you permitted to begin that implementation like so, `void Ship::setPos(int new_x1, int new_y1, int new_x2, int new_y2)`?

Comment: I cannot change the Ship.h file, This problem is now resolved though thank you for the input!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `this` pointer:

```
this->x1 = x1; // etc.
```

Or qualify with the class name:

```
MyClass::x1 = x1; // etc.
```

Comment: Im getting a compilation error:  error: invalid use of 'this' in non-member function

Comment: Inside which function?

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches

```
void setPos(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
   this->x1 = x1; 
   this->y1 = y1; 
   this->x2 = x2; 
   this->y2 = y2;
}

void setPos(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
   Ship::x1 = x1; 
   Ship::y1 = y1; 
   Ship::x2 = x2; 
   Ship::y2 = y2;
}
```

If the function is defined outside the class then you have to write for example

```
void Ship::setPos(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
   this->x1 = x1; 
   this->y1 = y1; 
   this->x2 = x2; 
   this->y2 = y2;
}
```

EDIT: As for your code then these data members are set in corresponding constructors the following way
For example

```
AircraftCarrier( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2 )
{
   setPos( x1, y1, x2, y2 );
}
```

Also it is not clear where the name of a ship is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach. Change the names of the arguments:

```
void setPos(int xa1, int ya1, int xa2, int ya2)
{
  x1 = xa1;
  y1 = ya1;
  x2 = xa2;
  y2 = ya2;
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the names as stated above I am stuck with using this format.